# How to add a RefreshIndicator to a sub part of the list?

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have:

```
Title

Search Bar

ListItem
ListItem
ListItem
ListItem
```

I want the whole thing to scroll up (so the title and search bar disappear), but if the user pulls down, it should refresh the List.

Right now I have:

```
   Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(HEADER),
              TextField() # Search,
              SingleChildScrollView(
               child: RefreshIndicator(
                 child: ListView.builder(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   primary: false,
```

This doesn't work. The scrolling works, but when I pull down, I see the semi-circle at the very top and I get no refresh action triggered. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
Scaffold
  appBar: // put text in title and textfield in flexibleSpace of AppBar
  body: // ListView in RefreshIndicator
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SilverAppBar: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
        chldren:<Widget>[
           Title,

           Search Bar,
           
           Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: RefreshIndicator()
           ),
        ]))
```

here the main part is that in column refreshIndicator is in Expanded without it its not work, about your error try remove  SingleChildScrollView, its give your layout infinite height.

Comment: I got this error: `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.